# Symfony2 authentication by directly calling check_path

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

My firewall configurations works well when I log in via the login form defined in login_path. What I want is to log in without seeing or going login_path, but sending username and password parameters to check_path directly.

When I make a post request to the check_path with username and password, it seems symfony2 needs a cookie which is created in login_path by smyfony2 itself.

Is there a way to log in by sending username and password to check_path directly?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option named **require_previous_session** to allow calling check_path without going login_path. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

After setting this directive as false, I am available to log-in by calling directly check_path.